# Purpose of PNP transistors connected base to base in 1V/Octave synthesizer keyboard circuit

Tags: transistors, keyboard, synthesizer

The circuit below (found [here](https://electro-music.com/forum/topic-66640.html)) is designed to be used in a 1V/octave keyboard used to control a synthesizer. When the potentiometer is adjusted properly, pressing the buttons produces output voltages in increments of 1/12th of a volt. I understand the general functionality of the circuit, but am a little confused about the specifics. I understand that the op-amp with the NPN transistor in its feedback loop is a voltage controlled current source, and that adjusting the input voltage somehow adjusts the voltage at the top of the resistor chain, but I don't understand exactly what role the two PNP transistors play in that and why they are connected in the way that they are. I have tried to find other circuits with a similar transistor configuration to try and figure this out, but have been unsuccessful.

[image: 1V/octave keyboard schematic]

Answer (score 3):

> *I don't understand exactly what role the two PNP transistors play in
> that and why they are connected in the way that they are*

The two PNP transistors form what is known as a [current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror) hence, the current that flows through your keyboard is a (fairly) faithful reproduction of the current flowing down into the NPN transistor. NPN and PNP current mirrors: -

[image]

Image above from [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/current-mirrors/).

> *adjusting the input voltage somehow adjusts the voltage at the top of
> the resistor chain*

Nearly there; adjusting the pot sets the current into the left hand PNP transistor and, the output from the right hand PNP is a current out (rather than a voltage out). That current multiplied by the relevant keyboard resistance produces a voltage that is the right level for a 12th octave semitone keyboard.

As a side note - are you aware that what you have is a monotonic keyboard; if you press two keys, the upper key takes precedence.